# sqlplus ORA-12504 running sqlplus locally on oracle server host - but only as non oracle owner account

Tags: oracle, database-connection, sqlplus, tns

On various UX environments I run some shellscripts to gather software version info and push it back to a central server. One script does this for Oracle.

On a 12.1.0.2.0 Oracle server (Solaris 11.2 system), the oracle owner account can sqlplus into the local Oracle service, after running oraenv with ORACLE_SID set & ORAENV_ASK=no

Either of these syntaxes works:

`sqlplus oracle_ID/password`

`sqlplus oracle_ID/password@ORACLE_SID`

However a non oracle owner account can only use the

`sqlplus user_ID/password` syntax to connect to the local oracle service!

`sqlplus 'user_ID/password@"//hostname:1521/ORACLE_SID"'` - syntax also works perfectly.

Attempting to use the following syntax is broken - the first is the one of interest (& works across all other Oracle database hosts for all instances):

`sqlplus user_ID/password@ORACLE_SID`  -  `ORA-12504: TNS:listener was not given the SERVICE_NAME in CONNECT_DATA`

`sqlplus user_ID/password@"/ORACLE_SID"`  -  `ORA-12154: TNS:could not resolve the connect identifier specified`

`tnsping ORACLE_SID` connects with the service OK.

`ohost:~$ truss sqlplus user_ID/password@ORACLE_SID
truss: cannot trace set-id or unreadable object file: /apps/oracle/product/12.1.0.2/bin/sqlplus`

It would be best to have one consistent syntax across all my servers for the data gathering script and I was curious why the change of UNIX id would cause this anomaly. Any ideas or ideas how to debug? Thx A.

Update: 15-Apr-2020 - After more GoogFu answer lies in which 'adapter' the user account uses to resolve the 'alias'.

oracle owner uses 'TNSNAMES' adapter whereas monitor account uses 'HOSTNAME' and the HOSTNAME method sends a null SERVICE_NAME field in the CONNECT_DATA. I haven't spotted why the oracle owner uses the TNSNAMES method, yet. I've looked through shell environment variables for both UNIX id's and the oraenv sets up all the ones that refer to the ORACLE_HOME okay. Can't see anything specifically TNS or 'net' related...

Comment: Only to fetch the Oracle software version you actually need not connect to the instance. There are many ways to get that information at OS level.

Comment: Thank you, this is true, there are many workarounds, but I'm after configuration, OS resource utilisation etc. from the Oracle instance's persepctive, licence high watermarks (CPU) and patch levels etc. I was hoping to just hit Oracle as a single datasource for all of these. I'm not stuck, just after light, elegant code!

Answer (score 0):

Easy when you know how. Seems a little weird to answer my own question...

Simply, the tnsnames.ora file was not world (other) readable. Hence non dba-group accounts had to fall back to the HOSTNAME resolution method.

That was a merry waste of 4 hours. It's not the first time an Oracle installation has had over(?) zealous permissions set on a config or shared object file, inside a 'server' installation, that a genuine client process requires. I haven't looked specifically but it doesn't seem to be filed as a bug with Oracle.